# Find $f(x)$ such that $2 \int_0^x f(t) \,\mathrm dt = x(f(x)+2000)$

Tags: analysis, integral-equations

> Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be such that
>
> $$2 \int_0^x f(t) \,\mathrm dt = x(f(x)+2000)$$
>
> for every $x$. Find $f(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Where did you come across this problem? These are the kind of questions we would like to have an answer to before we get a chance to ask them. Showing that you've put an effort into a problem really makes it easier for someone else to put an effort into answering. It's easier to give you the answer you need when it is also the answer you deserve.

Answer (score 4):

There is another approach, but a bit longer. We can use the Laplace Transformation here also. By taking L.T. from the both sides and knowing that:

- $\mathcal{L}\left(\int_0^x f(t)dt\right)=\frac{1}{s}\mathcal{L}(f(t))$
- $\mathcal{L}(tf(t))=-(\mathcal{L}(f(t))'$

we have $$2\frac{Y(s)}{s}+Y'(s)=\frac{2000}{s^2}$$ This is a linear OE with respect to $\mathcal{L}(f)=Y(s)$ which has a general solution as $Y(s)=\frac{2000s+C_1}{s^2}$. Now try to take Inverse L.T.to find the proper $f(t)$.

Comment: Excellent, dear friend...And at the time of this posting (comment) you are very very close to $\color{blue}{\bf 30 \,\text{K}}$

Comment: Thanks so much for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$. Then by part 1 of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and Product Rule, we have:
$$
2f(x)=1\cdot(f(x)+2000)+x\cdot f'(x) \iff xf'(x)=f(x)-2000
$$
Let $y=f(x)$. Switching to Leibniz's Notation, we obtain a separable ODE:
$$ \begin{align*}
x\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= y-2000 \\
\int \dfrac{dy}{y-2000} &= \int \dfrac{dx}{x} \\
\ln|y-2000| &= \ln|x| +C \\
e^{\ln|y-2000|} &= e^{\ln|x|+C} \\
e^{\ln|y-2000|} &= e^Ce^{\ln|x|} \\
|y-2000| &= e^C|x| \\
y-2000 &= \pm e^Cx \\
y &= 2000+Kx \qquad (\text{where }K=\pm e^C)\\
\end{align*}$$

Hence, we have $\boxed{f(x)=2000+Kx}$, where $K$ is any real constant.

Comment: what about K? :c

Comment: @Plom The fact that there is still a $K$ in it tells us that the required function $f(x)$ is not unique, but has infinitely many answers. Indeed, this is very common when solving ODEs and other functional equations.

Answer (score 1):

If the expressions on the left and right or equal, they still should be if you differentiate each side with respect to $x$. Doing this,

$$
2 \ f(x) = \left(f(x) + 2000\right) + x \ f'(x)
$$

Simplifying,

$$
f(x) = 2000 + x \ f'(x)
$$

Rearranging and dividing through by $x$,

$$
f'(x) - \frac{1}{x}f(x) = -\frac{2000}{x}
$$

This is a first-order ODE that can by solved by finding the integration factor $I$ as follows:

$$
I = \exp \left[ \int -\frac{1}{x} dx \right]
\\
I = \exp \left[ -\ln\left|x\right| \right] = \frac{1}{x}
$$

Solving the ODE,

$$
\left( \frac{1}{x}f(x) \right)' = -\frac{2000}{x^2}
$$

Integrating both sides,

$$
\frac{1}{x}f(x) = \frac{2000}{x} + C
\\
f(x) = 2000 + Cx
$$

where $C$ is any real constant.

Comment: Note: The differential equation can also be solved using the method of separation of variables

Answer (score 0):

First "pull yourself by the hair" to prove that $f$ is differentiable: LHS is continuous in $x$. Therefore RHS is continuous in $x$, which means $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere except, maybe, $x=0$. This means LHS is differentiable everywhere except, maybe, $x=0$. Therefore the same is true for RHS, and also $f(x)$.

Now let $x \ne 0$ and equate the derivatives of both sides. This will give you a linear ODE of the first order which you can solve using basic ODE-solving tools.

Comment: yes, i already did that and i got to the equation that adriano ended up getting, but theres still K in it, cant we find that somehow?

Comment: ah, okay, thx guys